# How to calculate a sum of products of array elements using a fast Fourier transform?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, sum, fft

I have some binary array. For example, let my array is:

```
int a[] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}
```

I want to calculate the values based on this formula:

[image]

How to calculate this function, using a fast Fourier transform? I have a large array and I have to calculate this function many times. So, I want to be able to calculate this function quick.

Comment: So the 2i is the parameter of b, it can be anything between 0 and the array size, and you want to calculate b for any parameters quickly? Is it really necessary to use FT stuff?

Comment: @deviantfan, yes, the 2i is the parameter of b, it can be anything between 0 and the array size, and I want to calculate b for any parameters quickly. I do not know how to quickly calculate this function without FT. I believe that FT is not necessary.

Comment: Looks like you are doing a convolution product, therefore you can indeed fast things up with FFT. Have a look at [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem). Note that with FFT you will compute all the b values, if you only need few of them I think it is not a good idea.

Comment: My head hurts :) Joke aside, I never was a great mathematican, but I wonder if a simple loop and compiler optimization is so much slower that it isn´t worth using it. And it´s very easy to code...

Comment: Well, assuming you want all the b values, a naive algorithm will have complexity O(N^2) - N being the number of i. Whereas a FFT based algorithm would have a complexity O(N log(N) ). Therefore if you are going to very large N you can have a substantial benefit with FFT.

Comment: for more headache: [multidigit multiplication for mathematicans](http://cr.yp.to/papers/m3.pdf) (it also includes polynoms, i.e. your case)

Comment: @Tony, In my case, `O(n^2)` is too slow, but `O(n*log(n))` is a few second.

Comment: Ok, if you want all the b values, I don't think you can beat O(n*log(n)). Hope you are more inclined to mathematics than  deviantfan =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation you are making is basically a convolution and convolution in the time domain is simply multiplication in the frequency domain.So just get the FFT of `a` and multiply it with itself, then perform an IFFT to return to the time domain.So in short, you can calculate b by

```
b(2*i) = IFFT( FFT(a[0:2*i)]).FFT(a[0:2*i]) )
```

Answer (score -2):

```
void main()
{
    int i,k,sum=0; 
    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        for(k=0;k<2*i;k++) 
        {
            sum + =(a[k]*a[2*i-k]; // calculating B
        }
    }
    cout<<sum;
}
```